# Rounding up to nearest available time slot in PHP

Tags: php, date, rounding

I've been struggling with this for an hour or so and have come up blank. Basically I need to take the current time, add 30 minutes to it, and then round up to the next 15 minutes.

Examples:

- if it's now 20:00, result = 20:45
- if it's now 20:10, result = 20:45
- if it's now 20:16, result = 21:00
- if it's now 20:35, result = 21:15

My PHP is rusty and I've been getting mixed up with date add and round methods trying to get this to work and I know it's simple - have just run out of ideas!

Thanks

Comment: Post the code you have tried so far. People will be much more likely to help with some code to start with.

Comment: Should 23:55 round up to the next day, or should it just wrap around to the same 24 hour clock?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll add a solution as well:

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

$times = array();
$times[] = strtotime('00:07');
$times[] = strtotime('04:21');
$times[] = strtotime('20:00');
$times[] = strtotime('20:10');
$times[] = strtotime('20:16');
$times[] = strtotime('20:35');
$times[] = strtotime('23:15');


foreach($times as $time) {
    echo date('m-d-Y H:i', $time) . ' becomes ' . date('m-d-Y H:i:s', roundToNearestInterval($time)) . "<br />\n";
}


function roundToNearestInterval($timestamp)
{
    $timestamp += 60 * 30;
    list($m, $d, $y, $h, $i, $s) = explode(' ', date('m d Y H i s', $timestamp));
    if ($s != 0) $s = 0;

    if ($i < 15) {
        $i = 15;
    } else if ($i < 30) {
        $i = 30;
    } else if ($i < 45) {
        $i = 45;
    } else if ($i < 60) {
        $i = 0;
        $h++;
    }

    return mktime($h, $i, $s, $m, $d, $y);
}
```

Yields:

```
03-01-2012 00:07 becomes 03-01-2012 00:45:00
03-01-2012 04:21 becomes 03-01-2012 05:00:00
03-01-2012 20:00 becomes 03-01-2012 20:45:00
03-01-2012 20:10 becomes 03-01-2012 20:45:00
03-01-2012 20:16 becomes 03-01-2012 21:00:00
03-01-2012 20:35 becomes 03-01-2012 21:15:00
03-01-2012 23:15 becomes 03-02-2012 00:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks for this - seemed to be the best solution that worked for all time variations I could throw at it.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this: convert to unix timestamp, add 30 * 60, then divide by 15 * 60, apply ceil(), then multiply by 15 * 60, then convert back to date.

Comment: Hmm, thinking about it I think I'd need to work on the ceil() part - if it's dead on 20:00 then +30 would give 20:30 and ceil() won't change it. Nevertheless, the approach might help get you started :)

Answer (score 2):

You may need to update this a bit and test a few scenarios where the time is close to top of the hour.

```
<?php

$now = strtotime('now');
$timePlus30 = date('H:i', strtotime('+30 minutes', $now));

$minNow = date('i', strtotime($timePlus30));
$roundedMins = $minNow + ($minNow % 15);

$return = date('H', strtotime($timePlus30)) . ':' . ($roundedMins - 1);

?>
```

Comment: I think the rounding thing rounds down here, rather than up? Still, +1.

Comment: It does. I added in the comments that it may need to be updated and tested for minor changes like that. However, I did want to give a good idea of how to get started. And I fixed it now so that it will round up correctly.

Comment: So you'd want something like this, I think: `$roundedMins = $minNow + 15 - ($minNow % 15)` - remember that (1 % 15) is 1 :)

Answer (score 0):

not the most ellegant solution but it should work (un tested)

```
$hoursAndMins = explode(":",timeString); // should be "HH:MM"
$hours = $hoursAndMins[0]+(($hoursAndMins[1]+30)/60);
$mins = ($hoursAndMins[1]+30)%60;

if ($mins > 52){
   $mins = "00";
   $hours += 1;

}else if ($mins > 38){
    $mins = "45";
}else if ($mins > 23){
    $mins = "30";
}else if( $mins > 7){
    $mins = "15";
}else{
    $mins = "00";
}
echo $hours+ ":"+$mins;
```

[edit]  The other solution is much better i think but this one is more verbose